# Configure CORS for Azure Static Web App calling Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

I have Azure Static Web App, currently it's using Azure's domain, so it looks like this: `https://gray-forest-042cd9900.3.azurestaticapps.net/`

I also have an App Service, which is an API, based on Docker's image. I need to enable the CORS for the API so that my SWA can talk to it, but I can't whitelist my SWA because it doesn't fit Azure's definition of a valid URL:

[image]

FWIW, the Docker's image is from `otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib`. I've already set the CORS in the config.yaml file:

```
cors:
  allowed_origins:
  - https://localhost:7067
  - http://localhost:3000
  - https://basicdemoapi.azurewebsites.net
  - https://gray-forest-042cd9900.3.azurestaticapps.net/
```

But I'm still getting CORS error, which makes me assume Azure App Service does not read CORS settings from the image.

How do I proceed? I don't want to buy a domain just for my experimentation.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to remove the trailing slash (`/`) and you should not get the error.

So try to set the origin as `https://gray-forest-042cd9900.3.azurestaticapps.net` (without any slash in the end) and you will not get the validation error.